# Create empty dataframe in R with same columns

Tags: r

```
 names(U1)

[1] "username"     "review_count" "forum_posts"  "age"          "avg_interval"
[6] "avg_sim"      "class"
```

So how do I create an empty data frame U1.RN that will have same columns as U1?

Comment: Can I ask why you need a 0-row data frame? Depending on what you are going to do with it, it might be more efficient to do things a different way (e.g. I hope you aren't planning on filling this row by row in a loop?)

Comment: "e.g. I hope you aren't planning on filling this row by row in a loop?" - yeah, :(. What is the R-y way to do the equiv of [pseudocode] for(i in 1:6000) if (pred.U1.nb.c[i]=='unlabeled') U1.RN[j++,]<-U1[i,]  [/pseudocode], where pred.U1.nb.c is a vector I got from a predict(), and want to create a data frame by selecting those rows of U1 that predict spewed out? (... trying hard to be verbose and not confusing simultaneously)

Comment: In R, preallocate your storage! You know you want a 6000-row data frame ahead of the loop, so create one and fill it in row by row. Or even quicker; create a matrix of the correct dimension, fill that row by row, and then convert to a data frame, as matrices are much faster to work with. If you want more help (looks like you might not even need a loop, just some simple indexing and subsetting/insertion), can you start a new Q and provide a proper, small example of what you really want to do? If you do, I'll promise to look at it and give a go at an answer.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, here's the Q: http://tinyurl.com/26ugewv

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can do this:

```
U1.RN <- U1[0,]
```

Comment: Perfect ..... > U1.RN<-U1[0,]
> names(U1.RN)
[1] "username"     "review_count" "forum_posts"  "age"          "avg_interval"
[6] "avg_sim"      "class"       
> nrow(U1)
[1] 6000
> nrow(U1.RN)
[1] 0

Comment: +1 neat!!!!!!!! (the extra ! were to get round the min character limit, oh, wait, ... ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Along the lines of `df[0,]` you can also use a boolean mask which might make the code more readable:

```
 df[FALSE,]
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `dplyr`, there are a few good options:

```
slice(U1, 0)
filter(U1, FALSE)
filter(U1, NA)
```

The `slice` approach is probably clearest.

Comment: `filter(FALSE)` also works and is maybe a little clear of intent. `slice(0)` might be even better.

Comment: Agreed that `slice(0)` seems to be a winner on readability/clarity