# How to copy an object's structure (but not the data)

Tags: r

How do I copy an object's specifications, but not the data?

In my specific case I have a data frame and I want another data frame with the same column classes, the same column names, the same number of rows but without any data inside.

Comment: Duplicate of [Create empty dataframe in R with same columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269012/create-empty-dataframe-in-r-with-same-columns). Be sure to heed the warnings about not pre-allocating.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can't have no data and the same number of rows.  If you want no data then select the zeroth row.  For example, with the `cars` dataset

```
cars[0, ]
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
cars |> filter(FALSE)
```

If you want the same number of rows, then set the data values to be `NA`.

```
cars |> mutate(across(everything(), \(x) NA))
```

Comment: `cars[0, ]` will result in a list, not a data.frame. OP asked to create an empty data.frame.

Comment: @Markus Try `class(cars[0, ])`. It's a data frame.

Comment: @Richie ah.. I used `typeof(cars[0, ])` - I see my mistake now. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Or a 2-step version

```
 new.df <- cars
 new.df[] <- NA
```